# how to install specific version of geth using ppa?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, ethereum, go-ethereum

I am trying to install a specific version `v1.7.3` of `geth` using

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ethereum/ethereum
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt install ethereum
```

This installs the latest package available (geth v1.8.2). But I want another package with same package name ethereum but different content (1.7.3+build11486+zesty)

[image]

I need the commands to install v1.7.3. I have to use it in a dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

`geth` package version `v1.7.3` is only available on `ubuntu zesty` platform i.e. `ubuntu 17.04`.

If you want to install `ethereum` version `v1.7.3` with all its dependencies on `ubuntu 16.04` you can always use non-elegant solution to install packages from the `.deb` files.

The `Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget 
RUN wget https://launchpad.net/~ethereum/+archive/ubuntu/ethereum/+files/abigen_1.7.3+build11486+zesty_amd64.deb && \
    wget https://launchpad.net/~ethereum/+archive/ubuntu/ethereum/+files/bootnode_1.7.3+build11486+zesty_amd64.deb && \
    wget https://launchpad.net/~ethereum/+archive/ubuntu/ethereum/+files/ethereum_1.7.3+build11486+zesty_amd64.deb && \
    wget https://launchpad.net/~ethereum/+archive/ubuntu/ethereum/+files/ethereum_1.7.3+build11486+zesty_amd64.deb && \
    wget https://launchpad.net/~ethereum/+archive/ubuntu/ethereum/+files/evm_1.7.3+build11486+zesty_amd64.deb && \
    wget https://launchpad.net/~ethereum/+archive/ubuntu/ethereum/+files/geth_1.7.3+build11486+zesty_amd64.deb && \
    wget https://launchpad.net/~ethereum/+archive/ubuntu/ethereum/+files/puppeth_1.7.3+build11486+zesty_amd64.deb && \
    wget https://launchpad.net/~ethereum/+archive/ubuntu/ethereum/+files/rlpdump_1.7.3+build11486+zesty_amd64.deb && \
    wget https://launchpad.net/~ethereum/+archive/ubuntu/ethereum/+files/swarm_1.7.3+build11486+zesty_amd64.deb && \
    wget https://launchpad.net/~ethereum/+archive/ubuntu/ethereum/+files/wnode_1.7.3+build11486+zesty_amd64.deb
RUN dpkg -i *.deb && rm -vf *.deb
```

Comment: Thanks it worked.I am setting up a private net on docker (with each node in a container).When I executed this docker file i could set up the  container with geth running in it it but the node take a lot of time to mine and hashrate=0. Is it the version problem ??